# How can I add a class to a label?

Tags: 7, forms

I need to add a class name to certain labels created by Drupal's form API like this:

```
$form['name'] => array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => 'Prénom'
);
```

If I use the following, the `<textarea>` gets a class, but not the label.

```
$form['name']['#attributes']['class'] = array('myClass');
```

I'm looking for something similar that will add a class to the `<label>`.

Comment: You should also consider if you can't already target that field label with CSS using the parent container class for the field name, e.g `.field-name-field-myfield label{ color:red; }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot set a class to the label tag of the form element using Form API's properties. 
However, you can set a prefix and a suffix to wrap the element (label + textarea) and use some nested CSS selector to accomplish what you are trying to do.

```
$form['name'] => array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => 'Prénom'
  '#prefix' => '<div class="myClass">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>'
);
```

and in the CSS, you can select the label tag like this:

```
.myClass label {
  text-transform: uppercase; /* just for example */
}
```

Not a decent solution but that's how I usually do this, and have seen others do. 
`#attributes` is for the input element itself so it's correct your code adds the `myClass` class to the `textarea`.

Answer (score 6):

This [post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5014653/241546) says that the Drupal Form API does not support adding classes to labels, but it does contain a decent workaround:

> Instead, you could target it using the wrapper class for the field and label:
>
> ```
> .form-item-field-foo label {
>   /* CSS here */
> }
> ```

The API documentation for [theme_form_element_label()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_form_element_label/7) shows why labels aren't possible (at least not out-of-the-box): the attributes array is initialized in the theme function and populated with just two optional classes ('option' and 'element-invisible').

So, is it completely impossible? In fact, I think it can be done, but I must add that I haven't tried this myself. You could try to:

- Add a new `#label_attributes` property to some (or all) form elements using [hook_element_info_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_element_info_alter/7) in a custom module;
- Override theme_form_element_label() and make it merge the `$attributes` array with the value of `$element['#label_attributes']`.

If you're going to give this a try, please let us know if it worked.

Comment: Due to time constraints, I will go for the easier solution proposed by Ayesh K. This looks like a good solution though, it may help somebody else. +1

Comment: Plus 1 for mentioning the  theme_form_element_label() theme function

Comment: Workarounds: if requiring JS on the site is acceptable, tweaking the DOM is probably easiest. If not, another (mean) way would be to remove `'#title'` or set `'#title_display' => 'invisible'` and then just do `'#suffix' => '<label for="TheElementId" class="option">Display This Text</label>'`. That causes it to appear outside of the wrapper `<div>` Drupal uses for its form-input elements, but a CSS rule could make it look no different.

Answer (score 5):

On Drupal 8, do that simply by adding in your_module.module file

```
function your_module_preprocess_form_element(&$variables) {

  $element = $variables['element'];
  if (isset($element['#label_attributes'])) {
    $variables['label']['#attributes'] = array_merge(
      $variables['attributes'],
      $element['#label_attributes']
    );
  }
}
```

and add the #label_attributes on form creation :

```
$form['some_field'] = [
  [...]
  '#label_attributes' => [
    'some_attr' => 'some_value',
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Ayesh's answer I have included an example use case for such code. While marvangend's answer is much more Drupalesk it's a lot of digging for a very simple result. Keeping form specific elements & CSS bundled with said form is the general use case, allowing us to target & act on inner elements is a tiny bit more specific.

http://legomenon.io/article/drupal-7-adding-form-placeholder-attributes

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    // Waterfall.
    case 'webform_client_form_16':
    case 'webform_client_form_51':
    case 'webform_client_form_64':
    case 'webform_client_form_78':
      $exclude = array('select', 'radios', 'checkboxes', 'managed_file');
      foreach ($form['submitted'] as $name => $component) {
        if (!in_array($component['#type'], $exclude) && $name != '#tree') {
          $form['submitted'][$name]['#prefix'] = '<span class= "label-invisible">';
          $form['submitted'][$name]['#suffix'] = '</span>';
          $form['submitted'][$name]['#attributes']['placeholder'] = $component['#title'];
        }
      }
      $form['#attached']['css'] = array(
        drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/css/mymodule.form.css',
      );
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a relatively easy way to accomplish this using the Fences D7 module.  This module comes with a lot of template files to customize the fields.  Edit the field that you would like to give a unique class to and change the wrapper markup to something relevant for you.  After that, find the corresponding template file within the module and copy it into your sites/all/themes/THEME_NAME.

Before

```
<span class="field-label"<?php print $title_attributes; ?>>
  <?php print $label; ?>:
</span>
```

After

```
<span class="<?php print $label; ?> field-label"<?php print $title_attributes; ?>>
  <?php print $label; ?>:
</span>
```

By adding in `<?php print $label; ?>` , it prints the name of the field as a class, allowing you to target all of the field-labels individually.  I hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

It's dirty, but you can add HTML to the '#title'-property:

```
$form['some_element'] = array(
  '#type'          => 'textfield',
  '#title'         => '<span title="HELP!">'.t($subchildlabel).'</span>',
  '#default_value' => …
) 
… 
);
```

I'm surprised myself it works. I would think Drupal would filter this out, but no. So, you can wrap the label with another class:

```
<label for="edit-m-vernacularname" class="inline"><span title="HELP!">Common name
</span> </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do tis is to write a bit of jQuery that finds the label for the field and uses the addClass method to add the class.

Drupal puts a unique class in the the div wrapper for each field. Inspect your source to find the class, and you can then jQuery for the child label.

For example in Drupal 7

Create a js file for your theme.

Add in this

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.addLabelclass = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
        $(document).ready( function () {
            $("div.uniquefieldclass label").addClass("mylabelclass");
            }
            );
        }
};
}(jQuery));
```

Substitute uniquefieldclass for your class. This jQuery will add the class mylabelclass to the label

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).