# How to modify attributes of fieldset-wrapper?

Tags: theming, forms

It's similar and connected to [How to modify attributes of <label> in form definition function?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/94555/how-to-modify-attributes-of-label-in-form-definition-function) - This time I want to ask how to modify attributes of a `<div class="fieldset-wrapper">`. HTML structure of a fieldset is:

```
<fieldset id="some-id" class="well-small form-wrapper vertical-tabs-pane">
  <legend>
    <span class="fieldset-legend">
      Lorem Ipsum
    </span>
  </legend>
  <div class="fieldset-wrapper">
    <span class="some-field">
      <!-- Irrelevant -->  
    </span>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

I need class `well-small` directly on a fieldset-wrapper div. But if I apply it to a fieldset itself, it appears when you see it in sample above. When I move it one level down, well, there are only fields there, so it's one level too far instead of one level too close to the document root. Is there a way to conditionally add classes and other attributes directly from form building functions?

CSS and JS workarounds are out of the scope for me. I know how to work around it. Now I'm asking to know how to do it directly in PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at [`theme_fieldset`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_fieldset/7) the `fieldset-wrapper` class is hardcoded and that div doesn't take any additional classes from the `$variables` array.

So looks like the only option is to override `theme_fieldset` in your `template.php` of the active theme. If your conditional variables are present in `$variables` then you could do the logic straight in the `theme_fieldset` override function (replace `mythemename` with the name of your theme)

```
function mythemename_fieldset($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  element_set_attributes($element, array('id'));
  _form_set_class($element, array('form-wrapper'));

  $output = '<fieldset' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>';
  if (!empty($element['#title'])) {
    // Always wrap fieldset legends in a SPAN for CSS positioning.
    $output .= '<legend><span class="fieldset-legend">' . $element['#title'] . '</span></legend>';
  }


  // Condition/logic here
  $class = '';
  if($variables['....'] == '....') {
    $class = ' well-small';
  }


  $output .= '<div class="fieldset-wrapper'.$class.'">';
  if (!empty($element['#description'])) {
    $output .= '<div class="fieldset-description">' . $element['#description'] . '</div>';
  }
  $output .= $element['#children'];
  if (isset($element['#value'])) {
    $output .= $element['#value'];
  }
  $output .= '</div>';
  $output .= "</fieldset>\n";
  return $output;
}
```

Otherwise, a more elegant solution (by @Mołot) would be to supply use `drupal_attributes` like so:

```
mythemename_fieldset(&$variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  element_set_attributes($element, array('id'));
  _form_set_class($element, array('form-wrapper'));

  $output = '<fieldset' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>';
  if (!empty($element['#title'])) {
    // Always wrap fieldset legends in a SPAN for CSS positioning.
    $output .= '<legend><span class="fieldset-legend">' . $element['#title'] . '</span></legend>';
  }

  $element['#wrapper-attributes']['class'][] = 'fieldset-wrapper';

  $output .= '<div' . drupal_attributes($element['#wrapper-attributes']) . '">';
  if (!empty($element['#description'])) {
    $output .= '<div class="fieldset-description">' . $element['#description'] . '</div>';
  }
  $output .= $element['#children'];
  if (isset($element['#value'])) {
    $output .= $element['#value'];
  }
  $output .= '</div>';
  $output .= "</fieldset>\n";
  return $output;
}
```

Comment: Good idea. Now, how do I override default theme functions? I can't quite get hook_theme_registry_alter to work in my template :/

Comment: It works just like a hook no? `theme_fieldset` will be overridden by `mytheme_fieldset` in `template.php` of `mytheme`.

Comment: Sadly, simply failed to work. `die()` implanted in it to test didn't happened. Will see in module.

Comment: Don't think it'll work from a module sadly either. It **should** work in template.php ... strange.

Comment: Could you tell me how? I hardly ever touched form elements theming functions yet. I can't simply re-declare function with same name, as shown in your answer (PHP does not allow that), and neither `mytheme_fieldset` nor `mytheme_theme_fieldset` works. And I can't force neither `mymodule_theme_registry_alter` nor `mytheme_theme_registry_alter` to fire at all, no matter if I clear cache or theme registry...

Comment: @Mołot `THEMENAME_fieldset()` will definitely override `theme_fieldset()`, but theme overrides only work for the _active_ theme. Same with the hooks, if you're looking at a page in the admin theme, hooks for a different theme will never run. Could that be the problem?

Comment: @Mołot sorry if I didn't make it clearer, but `theme_fieldset` should be renamed to `omega_fieldset` if it's in template.php of a theme named `omega`.

Comment: @Clive, Beebee -  Nope. That was the first thing I tried, but hen I assumed I'm doing something wrong or I'm missing something and there is something more to it :| will play a bit more, if it's supposed to work as `mytheme_fieldset`, then I need to debug it, that's all. Beebee you was clear, that's my setup playing tricks ;)

Comment: @Mołot I smell another question about broken theme registry :P

Comment: @Beebee Nope :P I asked my sysadmin about logs, and he told me to try again... Dunno what he did but I guess it was broken cache indeed. But I don't need to know, it works now.

Comment: @Clive could you please purge comments? Beebee what I finally did was `$element['#wrapper_attributes']['class'][] = 'fieldset-wrapper';  $output .= '<div ' . drupal_attributes($element['#wrapper_attributes']) . '>';`
 Now I can use `#wrapper_attributes` just like `#attributes` in my form definition. Consider adding it to your answer as alternative if you please, I think it's a bit more elegant (but still, not worth a separate answer as it's just a variation of yours).