# How to add class to individual radio item inside "radios"?

Tags: theming, forms

I need to style my radios as tabs. So I created a form element like this:

```
$form['important_categories'] = array (
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#label' => NULL,
  '#attributes' => array (
    'class' => array (
      'radioTabs',
    ),
  ),
);

foreach ($important_categories as $id_important_category => $important_category_name) {
  $form['important_categories']['#options'][$id_important_category] = $important_category_name;
  if(!isset($form['important_categories']['#default_value'])) {
    $form['important_categories']['#default_value'] = $id_important_category;
  }
}
```

This properly sets options, and sets first element as default. However, it add classes in two places. Here I wanted it:

```
<div id="edit-important-categories" class="form-radios radioTabs">
```

Here I didn't:

```
<input id="edit-important-categories-22" class="radioTabs form-radio" type="radio" value="22" name="important_categories">
```

On individual radio, I need `radioTab` *(singular, not plural)*, and on default one also `radioTabDefault`.

Is there any built-in method to get this? Or do I need to alter my theme, [like I did for labels](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/94555/16495)? If so, what function I should modify?

Comment: I know about [this request and solution](https://www.drupal.org/node/1612596), but it changes core function, and I failed to figure out how to do it at module or theme level instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No there's nothing built-in for this (take a look at [`form_process_radios()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_process_radios/7), nothing in there that would let you specify individual classes).

No need to hack core though like in the solution you linked to. Simply implement [`hook_element_info_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_element_info_alter/7), and *replace* the process function with your own, which will be based on the original `form_process_radios()`, but that can handle individual classes for options.

```
function MYMODULE_element_info_alter(&$info) {
  // You might want more advanced logic here, to replace instead of override altogether,
  // in case other modules have already altered the core info.
  $info['radios']['#process'] = array('MYMODULE_process_radios');
}

function MYMODULE_process_radios($element) {
  // ...
  return $element;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I usually stay far away from front-end, so I'm not as fluent with it as I would like to be. But this worked pretty OK.

Comment: Yeah it still does feel a bit awkward but I'm not sure there's a simpler way

Answer (score 5):

This is solution for Drupal 8.

Read [the Forms API documentation on the '#after_build' form element property.](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/6.x#after_build)

In Form Controller file - Radio button use '#after_build':

```
$form['myoptions'] = [
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#title' => t('My Options'),
  '#after_build' => array('custom_process_radios'),
//  ..
];
```

In your .module file code - defining the custom function.

```
/**
 * Processing Radios Element using #after_build property.
 * Adding the class attribute for individual radio button.
 * @element  array
 * @form_state  array
 * @return array
 */
function custom_process_radios($element, $form_state) {
  $options = array_keys($element['#options']);
  foreach($options as $values) {
    $element[$values]['#attributes']['class'][] = 'myclass';
  }
  return $element;
}
```

Read purpose of [all the properties for Form Element](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21FormElement.php/class/FormElement/8.2.x)